# how to make Paypal display an item_name with apostrophe correctly?

Tags: paypal, drupal, drupal-7

My Drupal site has a donation form which will redirect to Paypal on submit to process the donation. However, when a campaign (a node where you can donate to) has a title that contains *'s*, Paypal displays it with HTML characters.

The following lines, which are inside a function, pass the value from my donation form to Paypal and redirect there.

```php
$paypal = array(
  'cmd' => '_donations',
  'business' => $client_paypal_acct, // PayPal account email
  'bn' => 'GM_Donate_WPS_US', 
  'page_style' => 'primary',
  'item_name' => $this->params['campain_title'], // all other may need not be placed here as this variable is only needed for my query.
);
$query = http_build_query($paypal, '', '&');
$url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . $query;
drupal_goto($url);
```

Comment: Show some code, users can't tell whats going on without seeing code.

Comment: did you try  for ' = &apos; or try addcslashes() function

Comment: sorry @DeepakSrinivasan for not being clear, but the variable assigned to 'item_name' is a form submission value. should this work?
'item_name' => addcslashes($this->params['campain_title'])

Comment: i think so,even if its in form submit the value is displayed as html right?did you try that